# Does impala cache some data after queries

Tags: impala

I am new to Impala, I do some test cases on Impala.
I found similar SQLs is much faster when I called second time .

For example:

- table1 = 4B rows
- table2 = 50M rows

*1st query*: `select * from table1 where id in (select id from table2 where xxx < 10000)` 
**(20 seconds)**

*2nd query*: `select * from table1 where id in (select id from table2 where xxx < 9999)` 
**(10 seconds)**

*3rd query*: `select * from table1 where id in (select id from table2 where xxx < 100)`
**(1 seconds)**

I guess Impala do some special cache, could anyone can tell me its reason?

Thanks.

Comment: I have read some blogs from http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_perf_stats.html
But i didn't find any statistic and cache in tables or columns stat in my tables;

Answer (score 5):

Impala uses the cache of the OS and additional HDFS Caching.

An excerpt from [Using HDFS Caching with Impala](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_perf_hdfs_caching.html):

"The Linux OS cache [...] only keeps the most recently used data in memory. Data read from the HDFS cache avoids the overhead of checksumming and memory-to-memory copying involved when using data from the Linux OS cache."

This may explain the difference in execution time between your 1st and 2nd queries. However, the reason that your 3rd query is much faster than the first two is probably not (only) caching but the fact that it only queries about 1/100th of the data (assuming a uniform distribution of xxx).

Answer (score 2):

When I posted a question about this on a user group mailing list, Cloudera’s Jean-Daniel Cryans explained that this could be due to OS page cache. OS will cache data from disks in its page cache the first time it is accessed. Queries that hit tables that have not been read before will cause data to be read from disks, while tables that are already pre-loaded to page cache will be much faster as they are fetched from RAM. We observed the same thing with native Impala queries. We ran a few tests, restarting Impala and/or Kudu and could reproduce this by resetting the page cache. For this reason, we measured separately the execution time for the very first run after page cache reset, and the execution time for 3 consecutive runs after the first one. Tests were repeated 3 times, recycling the cache for each loop.

In other words, Impala does not cache results of the queries but would simply cache files from disks that it has to use to process your query.